# Get string array from C using marshalling in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c, marshalling

My c code is like

```
void GetCharArray(char* arrayNew[5])
{
    arrayNew[0] = "Test";
    arrayNew[1] = "Test2";
    arrayNew[2] = "Test4";
    arrayNew[3] = "Test5";
    arrayNew[4] = "Test6";
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void GetCharArray(char* arrayNew[5]);
```

I want to get the array populated with string in my C# code

```
[DllImport(@"C:/Test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern void GetCharArray([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst=5)] string[] sbOut);

List<string> testStr = new List<string>();
GetCharArray(test.ToArray());
```

I want my `testStr` to be populated with strings from C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution

```
public static extern void GetCharArray(IntPtr[] results);

IntPtr[] pointers = new IntPtr[1000];
GetCharArray(pointers);
string[] results = new string[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    results[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pointers[i]);
}
```

I hope it helps someone else.

Comment: You just picked up 1000, but what if I don't know the length of the array?

Answer (score 0):

As addition to your own answer (sorry, can't comment yet).

If you have an array with variable length, you could simply make 2 functions.

The first just returns the length of the needed array and the second passes an predefined array with the given length of the first function as you do it with your 1000.

At least that's how I could solve the problem.

Answer (score -3):

Without discussing the correctness of your syntax i think the following link would help you further.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-char-array-string

Comment: I don't see how this answer is helpful.